# How do I add to a table and then use the id for a different query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have three tables, which I create with these queries:

```
create table parents(
    rowid serial primary key,
    display_name varchar,
    unique(display_name)
);

create table clients(
    rowid serial primary key,
    parent int,
    display_name varchar,
    foreign key (parent) references parents(rowid),
    unique(display_name, parent)
);

create table datapoints(
    rowid serial primary key,
    client int,
    val float8,
    foreign key (client) references clients(rowid)
);
```

I am getting data which contains parent name, client name and some value. Each time I get this data, I want to add rows to the datapoints table. I also want to add rows to the clients and parents table, but only if the data I received has unrecognized names.

For example, I might get this data:

"parent1-client1-123.0"

What I would like to achieve is to process this data (in a query), this way:

Insert a row to the "parents" table, if needed.

Insert a row to the "clients" table with the appropriate parent id (obtained in the previous step?), if needed.

Insert a row to the "datapoints" table with the appropriate client id (obtained in the previous step?).

How can I manage this with queries? The programmer in me wants to write:

- Insert into parents if needed. Save the id of appropriate parent in a variable "current_parent"
- Insert into clients if needed, using the "current_parent" variable. Save the id of the appropriate client in a variable "current_client".
- Insert into datapoints, using the "current_client" variable from the prev. step.

But obviously this is not how sql works, right? And what if, instead of these three "nested" tables I have 5, or 10?(!)

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres can return the generated key on an insert. Unfortunately, when it encounters an existing unique key and an `on constraint` clause it does not return the existing key. (A guess, but you have probably discovered this.) However the programmer in you is not far off. Instead of *retrieve and save the id* you retrieve *retrieve and use* directly via a select. If needed for subsequent operations you just 'repeat' the retrieval. So with 3 levels you retrieve the first level value (parent rowid) for the 2nd level (client) and 3rd level (datapoints). The best (imho) just create a procedure which handles the 3 levels. Further, break down the input into is components before calling the procedure. The resulting procedure becomes:

```
create or replace procedure establisth_parent_client_datapoint(
                            parent_name_in  varchar
                          , client_name_in  varchar
                          , val_in          float8
                          ) 
  language sql 
as $$
    insert into parents (display_name)
         values (parent_name_in) 
         on conflict (display_name)
            do nothing;
                        
    insert into clients(display_name, parent) 
         select client_name_in 
              , p.rowid 
           from parents p 
          where p.display_name = parent_name_in 
        on conflict (display_name, parent)
           do nothing; 
          
    insert into datapoints(val, client) 
         select val_in, c.rowid 
           from parents p            
           join clients c 
             on ( c.parent = p.rowid) 
          where c.display_name = client_name_in
            and p.display_name = parent_name_in; 
$$;
```

since I do not know your development language I will supply examples in a Postgres `DO block`. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e625762c27d62b5cb58b4df92209e0cc).  
As far as having 5-10 nested tables, you just need to repeat the basic process for each. Of course with 10 nested tables, I would probably question the design.